# how to make FactoryBoy create a temporary directory?

Tags: python, factory-boy

I'd like to have FactoryBoy create a Django model instance for me, and then also create a temporary directory.

I've tried a few things:

```py
class OrganizationFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization

    some_directory = tempfile.mkdtemp
```

and

```py
    some_directory = tempfile.mkdtemp()
```

and

```py
    @factory.lazy_attribute
    def some_directory(self):
        return tempfile.mkdtemp()
```

When I try to use `some_directory` in my tests, the value is always None.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand what happens, the best will be to dive into factory_boy's internals.

#### factory_boy internals

There are separate phases in a `Factory`'s life:

1. **The declaration**

When Python imports the module containing a `class Factory` declaration, that class's definition is handled to a special metaclass in factory_boy's source code.
The metaclass reads all defined class attributes and methods, analyses them, and stores them in a specific way.

2. **Using the factory**

When your code uses `MyFactory()`, the class starts **building** an instance, according to the following steps:

1. Evaluate the declarations: each `LazyAttribute`, `SubFactory`, etc. is asked to generate its value;
2. Pass the resulting parameters to the `Meta.model` class constructor ­— this provides an instance of said class;
3. Ask all post-generation declarations (`RelatedFactory` and co) to work on the generated object — note that any value returned from those declarations is thrown away
4. Return the instance.

#### Solving your issue

In your case, I believe the issue might be that `some_directory` is either not a valid kwarg for your model's `__init__`, or replaced by some magic on your model class.

The simplest way would be to work on the post-generation level:

```py
class OrganizationFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization

    @factory.post_generation
    def some_directory(org, *args, **kwargs):
        tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        # Attach the generated temporary directory to the generated organization.
        org.some_directory = tmpdir
```